# SQL Server 2008 Rank with a pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

Current results:

```
ID    Keyid       PersonID     Rank
------------------------------------
 1     4678         9           1
 1     4678         8           2
 23    1234         7           1
 2     4321         6           1
 2     4321         5           2
```

Results I would like to see

```
ID    Keyid       Rank1       Rank2
------------------------------------
1     4678        9           8
23    1234        7         blank
2     4321        6           5
```

current query:

```
SELECT top 1000
    nm.ID,
    aj.KEYID,
    nm.PERSONID,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY nm.ID, aj.PERSONID ORDER BY nm.ID, aj.KEYID, nm.ID) as [Rank]
FROM  
    nm WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN  
    aj WITH(NOLOCK) ON aj.KEYID = nm.KEYID
WHERE 
    ID IS NOT NULL and ID <> '' AND ID <> 0
GROUP BY 
    nm.ID, nm.PERSONID, aj.KEYID
```

I have tried a pivot solution but cannot succeed. Any help would be appreciated, keep in mind there are thds of rows to display...

Comment: Trying to create a subquery to produce the results I desire.

Comment: Are you only ever going to have 2 ranks per person?

Comment: No, I could have more then 2 ranks per person.

Comment: I'm guessing my desired results cannot be created? I'll take any other suggestions someone might have.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result a few different ways.  You can use an aggregate function along with some conditional logic or you can use the PIVOT function.

Aggregate function with conditional logic, like a CASE expression would be:

```
select id, keyid,
  Rank1 = max(case when [rank] = 1 then personid end),
  Rank2 = max(case when [rank] = 2 then personid end)
from
(
    --- replace with your current query
    select id, keyid, personid, 
    [rank] 
  from yourquery
) d
group by id, keyid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5c6d/4)

Using the PIVOT function:

```
select id, keyid, rank1, rank2
from 
(
  --- replace with your current query
  select id, keyid, personid, 
    [rank] = 'Rank'+cast([rank] as varchar(2))
  from yourquery
) d
pivot
(
  max(personid)
  for [rank] in (Rank1, Rank2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5c6d/5)

Now you have commented that you will have an unknown number of `rank` values.  In that case, you will have to use dynamic sql to get a list of all ranks to convert to columns. The code would be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Rank'+cast([rank] as varchar(2))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select [rank]
                      from yourquery
                    ) d
                    group by [rank]
                    order by [rank]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, keyid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              --- replace with your current query
              select id, keyid, personid, 
                [rank] = ''Rank''+cast([rank] as varchar(2))
              from yourquery
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(personid)
                for [rank] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5c6d/6). You'll replace the subquery used here with your current query and all of these give a result:

```
| ID | KEYID | RANK1 |  RANK2 |
|----|-------|-------|--------|
| 23 |  1234 |     7 | (null) |
|  2 |  4321 |     6 |      5 |
|  1 |  4678 |     9 |      8 |
```